# How can I set the value of a dropdownlist according to the action of another dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in C# and asp.net.

In my work , a particular webform consist two dropdownlist whose IDs are respectively "DepartFrom" and "DepartTo". Each list consist the same text items. Texts are "Dhaka, Chittagong, Sylhet, Cox'sbazar".

Now I want to action as follows :

1. When I select "Dhaka" in "DepartFrom" list it will not appear in the "DepartTo" list, but the others will.
2. When I select 'Text' except 'Dhaka' in 'DepartFrom' list, only 'Dhaka' will appear in the "DepartTo" list.

I have tried this but it's not working.

```
`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (DepartFrom.Items.ToString() == "Dhaka")
                {
                    DepartTo.Items.Clear();
                    DepartTo.Items.Add("Chittagong");
                    DepartTo.Items.Add("Cox'sbazar");
                    DepartTo.Items.Add("Sylhet");
                    DepartTo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    DepartTo.Items.Clear();
                    DepartTo.Items.Add("Dhaka");
                    DepartTo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }

        }
`
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `AutoPostBack="true"` to your dropdownlist who define behavior of second dropdownlist, and also define `SelectedIndexChanged` event on this dropdownlist

```
asp:DropDownList ID="DepartTo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void itemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var control = (DropDownList)sender; 
   if(control.SelectedValue == "")
   {
     .....
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help... Anyway, I won't hesitate to learn from u..it will be my pleasure to learn from u. :p :p –

Comment: I'am happy to help you Sazzad

Comment: Tried it..earlier..and  it's done.. thanks.. :)

Comment: i'am happy to help you Sazzad

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long but easy to understand way:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DepartFrom" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="fromSelected">
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DepartTo" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind.

```
string[] items={"Dhaka", "Chittagong", "Sylhet", "Cox'sbazar"};
protected void fromSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if((sender as DropDownList)!=null)
  {
   DepartTo.Items.Clear();
   foreach(string str in items)
    {
       if((sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.ToString()!=str)
       {
        DepartTo.Items.Add(str);
       }
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. I tried it with slight changed. But I had to do it manually and the system did not accepted the array.. so I had to declare each in separate variable. Anyway, I won't hesitate to learn from u both.. :p :p

Comment: I updated the code now it should work.